# How to make t() of react-18next to return string

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-i18next

I am using typescript and react-18next library for translations.
I have simple component like:

```
const Box = (props: {
  msg: string;
}): React.ReactElement<{ msg: string }> => { return <p>{props.msg}</p> }
```

And I am trying to use it like:

```
<Box msg={t("common.message")} />
```

But I am getting typescript error:

```
Argument of type '"common.message"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TemplateStringsArray | Normalize<
```

All I am trying to make is to translate key and pass it to string prop.

Comment: Take a look at https://react.i18next.com/latest/typescript#type-errors it looks related

Comment: How do you import the t function?

Comment: `const { t } = useTranslation();`

Comment: Now I realized that this is happening when using keys like `login.msg` but when I use root variable like `msg` it works.

Comment: @apokryfos link that you provided is solution to this issue ty.